# Count Matches between two lists in python and return matches

Tags: pandas, dataframe, count

I am trying to add a count of all the matches between dataframes a & b

```
df2['Count'] = len(set(a) & set(b))
df2.head(5)
```

But it only returns "0"

Data for a:

| Result | Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | D-level | R-level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| numpy | de | LA | 11060303 | 8 | NaN |
| FRA | Paris | YouTube | 56764332 | 1 | 4.0 |

Here is the data for b:

```
numpy
File Edit View —Insert_ © Cell~—«KKemmel_«- Widgets. Help tT | Python 3 (ipykernel) @
@ B & % mR MC PM Code » 2

YouTube

import numpy
```

Desired output should be a total of matches between a and b appended to the dataframe:

| Result | Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | D-level | R-level | No of matches? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| numpy | de | LA | 11060303 | 8 | NaN | **(1 unique match)** |
| FRA | Paris | YouTube | 56764332 | 1 | 4.0 | **(1 unique match)** |

Best,

Comment: What is `a` and `b`???

Comment: Sorry, both are dataframes. I will update the post

Comment: Can you provide a sample of `a` and `b`? Do a and b have the same number of columns?

Comment: The match based on what, which column?!

Comment: @Corralien Hi, a is a .csv file similar to the table above and b is random data. b does not have collumes

Comment: Your code is not reproducible. Try to update your post with data for `a` and `b` as plain text (not image) please

Comment: @Phoenix Hi, any matches found in b (Which is a unordered list) and in a (which is a .csv file) So if b contains "YouTube" this should count as 1 unique match.

Comment: @Corralien I have added the data for both a and b.

Comment: If there is 'Python 3' in dataframe 1, do you consider this as match?

Comment: @Phoenix If it was found in a, yes. 

At the moment no, because it is not in the a.

Comment: Why YouTube does not match?

Comment: @Corralien Just made correction. It does match.

Comment: However, Python 3 is found in the single line but you meant if the Python 3 should be a single word as YouTube and numpy to say there is a match, right?

Comment: @Phoenix Yes, you are correct.

Comment: A last question: Is `NaN` a string to match or we have to ignore it?

Comment: @Corralien In principal no, but ideally we want to count all matches across all rows.

Answer (score 0):

lets consider the dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['a','c'],['a','b']])
```

Running `set(df)` results in `{0,1}` which is not the set of entries you want. What you need to do is get a flattened list of entries (see [How to make a flat list out of a list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists))

```
def flatten_df_values(df):
    return [item for sublist in df.values for item in sublist]
```

then if you have a second dataframe

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['f','c'],['a','b']])
```

you can perform your operation and get

```
set(flatten_df_values(df)) & set(flatten_df_values(df2)) = {'a', 'b', 'c'}
```

if you want to get the repeated rows you can simply use merge with its default `how='inner'`

```
df.merge(df2,on=list(df.columns))
```

This will result in a Dataframe containing the duplicated rows. In our example case

```
   0  1
0  a  b
```

Note that you can modify the `on` parameter to include only the columns you want.